# I need circuit able to detect the minimum value of a positive signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I'm asking if there is a circuit configuration able to store the minimum positive value (Vmin) of a stochastic signal like in the picture.

I don't know its main value since what i need is a real-time detection of an acquired random signal, therefore i need something similar to a peak detector able to store Vmin (I repeat, it's always a positive value).

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: inverting buffer and peak detect? but why not in the digital domain?

Comment: Show what value you mean on the picture and embed the picture into your question. Don't show two waveforms because that confuses. Explain how you want the measurement process to restart/reset.

Comment: (1) "Store"? As a digital or analog value? (2) If it's analog then how long you want it held for. i.e. What is the acceptable sample and hold drift rate? (3) There is no timescale on your chart. Are those months or what? (4) As Andy says, what resets the process?

Comment: Your edit is not good. Your top comment on the image points to a value somewhere between the short-term peak and minimum as does the second. What are the four tick marks? What does ND and PD mean?

Comment: (1) Analogue (2) Till a smaller peak than the actual min (3) It should not matter, i need a conceptual solution, the i'll choose eventually the components values (4) Process will resets when i choose to turn off the supply, it isn't a key point of my question.

Comment: I took another example which should be clearer... In the image above, i need to detect the "0.96V" value

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a good question _except_ for the image. I have no idea what you're trying to show. What's "PD" and "ND"? 0.96 is so far away from anything that it's impossible to see what it's indicating, and there are four black markers in the waveform, two which are somewhat explained but hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can deal with offsets, then you can use a modified LP filter.

[image]

[Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2035.60246606707791%2050%205%2050%0AO%20352%20464%20432%20464%201%0AO%20352%20368%20432%20368%201%0AR%20176%20416%20144%20416%204%205%2040%205%200%200%200.01%0Ac%20288%20464%20288%20512%200%200.00001%204.488504679592585%0Ag%20288%20512%20288%20528%200%0Ad%20224%20464%20288%20464%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20224%20416%20224%20464%200%0Aw%20288%20336%20288%20368%200%0Ar%20288%20304%20288%20336%200%20100000%0Ag%20288%20416%20288%20432%200%0Ac%20288%20368%20288%20416%200%200.00001%200.2914923635824997%0Ad%20288%20368%20224%20368%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20224%20416%20224%20368%200%0Ar%20176%20416%20224%20416%200%201%0AR%20288%20304%20288%20272%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20288%20464%20352%20464%200%0Ar%20352%20464%20352%20512%200%20100000%0Ag%20352%20512%20352%20528%200%0Aw%20288%20368%20352%20368%200%0Ao%202%2016%200%204354%205%200.0015625%200%202%202%203%0Ao%201%2016%200%204354%202.5%200.1%201%201%0Ao%200%2016%200%204354%205%200.1%202%201%0A) to simulation.

- The left graph = square wave with 1% pulses, -peak = 0 V, +peak = 5 V.
- The middle graph = min(the square wave) + offset
- The right graph = max(the square wave) - offset
- The 1 Ω resistor is there for simulation purposes.

The offset is non-linear, but fairly linear in the region that it might be used. In this particular setup, the offset is about 500 mV, which stems from the forward voltages of the diodes. These two offsets can easily be removed in software with a simple addition and subtraction.

The input impedance is pretty low, so you might want to use an op-amp acting as a buffer right before it goes into the diodes. Otherwise you will *load* the noise, so what you measure will show a less value than if your measurement hadn't been there.

---

If you, for some reason cannot perform addition and subtraction in software, or if the non-linearity from the forward voltage of the diodes are either unknown, messy, or just too non-linear, then you can use this setup instead:

[image]

[Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2035.60246606707791%2050%205%2050%0AO%20416%20496%20496%20496%201%0AO%20416%20352%20496%20352%201%0AR%20144%20512%20112%20512%204%205%2040%205%200%200%200.01%0Ac%20352%20496%20352%20544%200%200.00001%205.043986576658863%0Ag%20352%20544%20352%20560%200%0Ad%20304%20496%20352%20496%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20352%20256%20352%20304%200%20100000%0Ag%20352%20400%20352%20416%200%0Ac%20352%20352%20352%20400%200%200.00001%200.0000029382145806651644%0Ad%20352%20352%20304%20352%201%200.805904783%0AR%20352%20256%20352%20224%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20352%20496%20416%20496%200%0Ar%20416%20496%20416%20544%200%20100000%0Ag%20416%20544%20416%20560%200%0Aw%20352%20352%20416%20352%200%0Aa%20176%20352%20256%20352%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200.0000029382145806651644%20-2.9638892571369942e-21%0Aw%20176%20336%20176%20304%200%0Aw%20176%20304%20352%20304%200%0Aw%20352%20304%20352%20352%200%0Aw%20176%20448%20352%20448%200%0Aw%20176%20480%20176%20448%200%0Aa%20176%20496%20256%20496%200%2015%20-15%201000000%205.043986576658863%20-2.9638892571369942e-21%0Aw%20352%20448%20352%20496%200%0Aw%20176%20368%20144%20368%200%0Aw%20144%20368%20144%20512%200%0Aw%20144%20512%20176%20512%200%0Ar%20304%20496%20256%20496%200%201%0Ar%20304%20352%20256%20352%200%201%0Ao%202%2016%200%204354%205%200.0015625%200%202%202%203%0Ao%201%2016%200%204354%200.00244140625%200.1%201%201%0Ao%200%2016%200%204354%2010%200.1%202%201%0A) to simulation.

- The graph's are the same as above
- The 1 Ω resistors are there for simulation purposes.

Here you are getting high impedance for free and proper max and min values. If you are going to go with this setup, then make sure the op-amp's output is in the range of the expected noise voltage + offset. So *if* you are going to use an LM358 as the op-amp (not something I recommend, because it's slow), then the negative voltage source for the op-amp would be at least -1 V for the negative output. Because the diode will have a forward voltage of maximum 1 V, and the most negative part of your noise will be 0 V I presume. And the positive voltage source would have to be 5 V (maximum noise) + 1 V (diode) + 1.5 V (LM358 isn't rail-to-rail) = 7.5 V.

---

Edit: Here's a [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%202.1831051418620846%2050%205%2050%0AO%20-32%20448%2048%20448%201%0AO%20-32%20352%2048%20352%201%0Ac%20-96%20448%20-96%20496%200%200.000001%204.227240710047341%0Ag%20-96%20496%20-96%20512%200%0Ad%20-160%20448%20-96%20448%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20-160%20400%20-160%20448%200%0Aw%20-96%20320%20-96%20352%200%0Ar%20-96%20288%20-96%20320%200%20100000%0Ag%20-96%20400%20-96%20416%200%0Ac%20-96%20352%20-96%20400%200%200.000001%201.2027010316308675%0Ad%20-96%20352%20-160%20352%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20-160%20400%20-160%20352%200%0AR%20-96%20288%20-96%20256%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-96%20448%20-32%20448%200%0Ar%20-32%20448%20-32%20496%200%20100000%0Ag%20-32%20496%20-32%20512%200%0Aw%20-96%20352%20-32%20352%200%0An%20-400%20416%20-432%20416%200%201%2040%208%200%200%200.5%0Av%20-336%20416%20-272%20416%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20-400%20416%20-336%20416%200%2010000%0Ac%20-336%20416%20-336%20480%200%208.199999999999999e-9%200.7232688913389462%0Ag%20-336%20480%20-336%20496%200%0Aw%20-192%20400%20-160%20400%200%0Aa%20-272%20400%20-192%20400%200%2015%20-15%201000000%203.2232366589723567%203.2232688913389462%0Aw%20-272%20384%20-272%20352%200%0Aw%20-272%20352%20-160%20352%200%0Ao%2022%204%200%2012546%205.288879382535469%200.0001%200%203%201%200%200%200%0A) for the first one with proper noise, and here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%207.010541234668786%2050%205%2050%0AO%20-48%20480%2032%20480%201%0AO%20-48%20336%2032%20336%201%0Ac%20-112%20480%20-112%20528%200%200.00001%204.423985626762107%0Ag%20-112%20528%20-112%20544%200%0Ad%20-160%20480%20-112%20480%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20-112%20240%20-112%20288%200%2010000%0Ag%20-112%20384%20-112%20400%200%0Ac%20-112%20336%20-112%20384%200%200.00001%200.21614114730245276%0Ad%20-112%20336%20-160%20336%201%200.805904783%0AR%20-112%20240%20-112%20208%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-112%20480%20-48%20480%200%0Ar%20-48%20480%20-48%20528%200%2010000%0Ag%20-48%20528%20-48%20544%200%0Aw%20-112%20336%20-48%20336%200%0Aa%20-288%20336%20-208%20336%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200.21614114730245276%203.453463780775298%0Aw%20-288%20320%20-288%20288%200%0Aw%20-288%20288%20-112%20288%200%0Aw%20-112%20288%20-112%20336%200%0Aw%20-288%20432%20-112%20432%200%0Aw%20-288%20464%20-288%20432%200%0Aa%20-288%20480%20-208%20480%200%2015%20-15%201000000%204.423985626762107%203.453463780775298%0Aw%20-112%20432%20-112%20480%200%0Aw%20-288%20352%20-320%20352%200%0Aw%20-320%20352%20-320%20496%200%0Aw%20-320%20496%20-288%20496%200%0Ar%20-160%20480%20-208%20480%200%201%0Ar%20-160%20336%20-208%20336%200%201%0Ag%20-384%20416%20-384%20432%200%0Ac%20-384%20352%20-384%20416%200%208.199999999999999e-9%200.9534637807752978%0Ar%20-448%20352%20-384%20352%200%2010000%0Av%20-384%20352%20-320%20352%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0An%20-448%20352%20-480%20352%200%201%2040%208%200%200%200.5%0Ao%201%2016%200%2012546%205.334908844991716%200.0001%200%204%200%200%2022%200%2022%203%0A) for the second one with proper noise.

Here's an image of them two side by side.

[image]

As you can see, they both have pros and cons. Op-amp = messier to set up, no op-amp = offsets.

Comment: @Fab92 Updated my answer so you can see which one that might be better to use, which is 100% up to you.

Comment: I already update your answer but i haven't more than 15 points of reputation, so the systems doesn't make public it! However, I've already accepted your answer as well. Thank you to helped me!

Comment: Ok, now It's visible :-)

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this is to use software in a microcontroller behind an A/D converter that samples the analogue signal at a rate faster than the analogue signal changes value. Then software can compare successive measured values to arrive at whatever algorithmic solution that you desire.

So if the bandwidth of your analogue signal is say something like 5 to 10 Hz then sample the A/D converter at say 1000Hz so that you can reasonably track the analogue changes. There are many modern microcontrollers that can easily manage 12-bit A/D conversions once per millisecond. You may have to condition and/or scale your analogue signal using an opamp or two to be able to use the widest possible measurement range of the A/D converter.